# Show all plans in Braintree, using PHP

Tags: php, braintree

I am using Braintree payment gateway in my PHP application. I am creating subscription page on which I want to show all plans, so that the customer can subscribe any of them. How can we show all plans using PHP?

I have used the following code:

```
    require_once ("../braintree/_environment.php");
    $plans = Braintree_Plan::all();
    print_r($plans);
```

but it shows nothing. I already have created a plan in my braintree account.

Following is the code for _environment.php file

```
 <?php
require_once('braintree-php/lib/Braintree.php');
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('merchantkey');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('publickey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('privatekey');
?>
```

Comment: I already have included environment.php with private, public and merchant keys. Following is the code of _environment.php file:

Comment: I have shown _environment.php file code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r("<pre>");
$plans = Braintree_Plan::all();
foreach ($plans AS $plan) {
    print_r("<br>PLAN");
    print_r("<br>    id                    = " . $plan->id);
    print_r("<br>    name                  = " . $plan->name);
    print_r("<br>    description           = " . $plan->description);
    print_r("<br>    price                 = " . $plan->price);
    print_r("<br>    currency              = " . $plan->currency);
    print_r("<br>    trialPeriod           = " . $plan->trialPeriod);
    print_r("<br>    billingDayOfMonth     = " . $plan->billingDayOfMonth);
    print_r("<br>    numberOfBillingCycles = " . $plan->numberOfBillingCycles);
 // print_r("<br>    billingCycle          = " . $plan->billingCycle);
}
print_r("</pre>");
```